# How to get if checkbox is checked on flask

Tags: python, flask, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap with Flask Python.

```
 request.form.get("name")
 #name is the name of the form element(checkbox)

 <label class="btn btn-danger pzt active">
     <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="1" data-id="0"> Check
 </label>
```

When checkbox is checked, parent label has class "active", I want to get if checked box is checked. Is there any way or methods?

Comment: What does `request.form.get("name")` return?

Answer (score 20):

you can try the following:

```
HTML:

<div class="checkbox">
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="edit"> New entry
</label>
</div>
```

In flask:

```
 value = request.form.getlist('check')
```

This will give you the value of the the checkbox. Here value will be a list.

```
value = [u'edit']
```

You can also get value of  multiple checkboxes with same name attribute.

Comment: If `request.form.getlist('name_attr')` returns 'on', it's likely that you haven't set the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with Flask, but I do know how HTTP works.

If you want to know if its checked on the server side, just check if that form field exists, if **request.form.get("name")** gives you NULL or exception, then the checkbox should be unchecked.

If you want to know it on the client side with javascript, you can use jQuery (as jQuery is a base component of Bootstrap) as **$('xxxx').is(':checked')** (replace xxxx with a valid selector).

Comment: But the checkbox has no attribute "checked" when i click on it. Label has "active" class or not.

Comment: @alpan if then, just make it $('xxxx').hasClass('active');

Comment: I'm not checking it with javascript, checking it with python flask

Comment: @alpan That's server side check. You should get it by **isChecked = 'name' in request.form && request.from.get('name') == '1'** (the value check is optional)